# Select values corresponding to keys that contain keywords

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following code which extracts the id of items containing a keyword:

```
>>> keywords = ['red', 'my', 'banana', 'red']

>>> items = list()
>>> new_item = {'text': 'your white apple', 'id': 1}
>>> items.append(new_item)
>>> new_item = {'text': 'my red orange', 'id': 2}
>>> items.append(new_item)
>>> new_item = {'text': 'my grape', 'id': 3}
>>> items.append(new_item)
>>> new_item = {'text': 'white banana', 'id': 4}
>>> items.append(new_item)
>>> new_item = {'text': 'red mango', 'id': 5}
>>> items.append(new_item)

>>> keyword_items = dict()

>>> for keyword in set(keywords):
>>>     keyword_items[keyword] = list()
>>>     for item in items:
>>>         if keyword in item['text'] and item['id'] not in keyword_items[keyword]:
>>>             keyword_items[keyword].append(item['id'])
>>> print(keyword_items)

{'banana': [4], 'my': [2, 3], 'red': [2, 5]}
```

But I need to optimize it to get faster results, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use a `set()` instead of a `list()` since you are removing duplicate ids.

Then, you can use list/dict comprehensions to make your code a lot shorter and efficient:

```py
keyword_items = {k:set(i['id'] for i in items if k in i['text'])
                 for k in keywords}
```

gives `{'banana': {4}, 'my': {2, 3}, 'red': {2, 5}}`

I am simply collecting all the ids for the items whose text contains the keyword, and storing them in a set. If you *really* want a list, then you can change `keyword_items` to:

```py
keyword_items = {k:list(set(i['id'] for i in items if k in i['text']))
                 for k in keywords}
```

Then, it would give: `{'banana': [4], 'my': [2, 3], 'red': [2, 5]}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
keyword_items=dict()
for keyword in set(keywords):
    keyword_items[keyword] = list()


dummy=[keyword_items[keyword].append(item['id']) for item in items for keyword in set(keywords) if keyword in item['text'] and item['id'] not in keyword_items[keyword]]
```